# Android Directory on SDCard Encryption

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes

I have a folder on an SDCard inserted into an Android tablet device.
Is it possible to Encrypt the folder (not the files) using AES or any other method? So that only a specific application with the key can Decrypt the folder and go through its content?

Thanks.

Comment: The decryption key can be extracted from the "specific application". This is nothing more that obfuscation, but sure, you could go through the files in a folder, throw them into some kind of container and encrypt the container.

Answer (score 0):

No, unless you're able to format the card with a filesystem that supports encryption, *and* you have a modified version of Android that will recognize, decrypt, and mount that filesystem.

Most of the time, the sdcard is just a basic FAT32 or similar filesystem with all the the features and limitations of that filesystem.